# Opening.csproj file opens the entire solution - I don't want the solution to be opened

Tags: visual-studio, csproj, solution

When I try to open a .csproj file through VS2017 - it opens the entire solution where other projects are also getting loaded. I am not sure on why this is occurring. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to edit the .cproj file itself?  If the project is in the same soluton as the other projects, then it will open the whole solution.

Comment: I am trying to open that particular project. Not the whole solution. The project is a part of the solution. The solution contains 20+ projects.I don't want all of them to be loaded.

Comment: VS 2017 has a lightweight solution load feature that should save you load time since the projects will be loaded as needed.

Comment: For me it does not happen. In VS17